# What exactly does "下ろしてもらい" in “帰りに私だけ駅前のカフェで下ろしてもらい...” refer to?

Tags: meaning

Context:

> 今日は母とお昼ご飯にパスタを食べに行きました。帰りに私だけ駅前のカフェで**下ろしてもらい**、...

From this context, is it possible to tell what kind of transport/vehicle is the author using?

Is the subject of "下ろしてもらい"  the driver of the vehicle which the speaker took?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammatically, the subject is 私. Most probably the vehicle is just a car (not a matter of language but of common sense).

Te-form + [もらう(#7)](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E8%B2%B0%E3%81%86/#je-75733) literally means *to have someone do something (as a favor)*. And [おろす(#3)](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/drop/#ej-25901) here is *to drop someone (from a vehicle)*. So おろしてもらう means *to receive the favor of being dropped off*.  (added) So the subject of おろす is (most probably) the mom or the driver and that of おろしてもらう is the speaker 私.

The second sentence is literally *I had mom drop me off at the cafe near the station on the way back*.

Comment: I suspect that when OP asked who is the "subject of 下ろしてもらい" there's a chance they meant who is the actual person doing 下ろす. So, just to make things clear, the grammatical subject of the sentence 私 and the agent of the action 下ろす are different in this sentence precisely because てもらう is used. I.e. 母は私を下ろす -> both the subject and the agent are 母, but in 母に[私は]下ろしてもらう -> the subject has shifted to 私, yet the agent is still 母, and the scene is exactly the same: Mom dropping me off.

Comment: Thank you all for your detailed explanations!
Now I understand "てもらう" better, and I can see the difference between the subject of "下ろしてもらい" and the agent of "下ろす".
But may I ask, everyone considers the agent of "下ろす" to be the author's mother, is this because the author used "~てもらう"? And if the author took a bus or a densha, wouldn't she use "~てもらう" for a driver?

Comment: @Theseus For buses or trains, おろしてもらう is not used  (If the subject asked the driver for a special favor to stop at an irregular spot, then おろしてもらう may be used). So Yes to *everyone considers the agent of "下ろす" to be the author's mother,*; but if there are other contexts (the speaker hitchhiked or the speaker's friend picked them up, for example), interpretation can change.

Comment: @sundowner Thanks again! I got it.